# Angular directive scope work differently with replace value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive with source code shown below:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["mytemplate.html"])
var thai =  angular.module("mytemplate.html", []).run(['$templateCache',
  function ($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('mytemplate.html', '<ul ng-if="true"> <li> <a ng-click="next()" href="javascript:void(0)">&raquo;</a> </li> </ul>');
  }
]);

thai.directive('myTop',function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    scope: {

    },
    templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.next = function () {
            alert('Hello!');
        };
    }
}
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thai_nguyen/z3j37aqb/).

When I click on the ">>" button, it works well (alert "Hello").  However if I change the `replace` value in directive from `false` to `true` (and click update code in fiddle), the alert no longer works.

I thought that the scope is detached, but I don't know why? Would you please teach me about the reason here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The javascript function you had assigned to the href in your anchor was the problem.  It works regardless of the replace value here.  https://jsfiddle.net/wxeumcy6/2/

Why this was preventing it from working, I'm not entirely sure.  But for anchors you can just say `href=""` or `href="#"` normally.

Comment: No, you've moved the ng-if condition from _ul_ to _a_ tag. If you change href but don't change ng-if condition, it's not worked.

Comment: Is there a reason you had the `ng-if` conditional?  I must have removed it thinking it was erroneous or left over from trying to find a resolution.

Comment: I do it in purpose. Because it's just demo, so I take it lean to read. Example, beside <ul>, we have many <li>, and the if condition effect to whole <ul> tag, not only <li> tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you set `scope: false`, it will fix your problem.

```
thai.directive('myTop',function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    scope: false,
    templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.next = function () {
            alert('Hello!');
        };
    }
}
});
```

You had `scope: {}` which creates an isolate scope. That was causing problems for the `ng-if` directive in your template.

Comment: I think _Isolate scope_ worked well with directive. As my description, if I used _Isolate scope_ and _replace value is false_, it's still worked well.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need a directive with `replace: true` and `scope: {}` on an element that shares scope with an `ng-if` directive? Can you use `ng-show` instead?

Comment: Thanks @georgeawg 
Actually, I want to use directive with some of parameters, but it's just demo, so I let it simplest case. 
I think _replace_ and _scope_ don't have relation. Here is _Attribute_ directive, so I think _replace=true_ just change whole template of directive to my div in controller template.

Comment: Correct: `replace` & the isolate scope are for the most part mutually exclusive (aside from those instances where other directive params are declared.  `replace = true` means that it will replace the DOM element where it's declared. If you have other attributes that the directive depends on, you then need to copy them over somehow or manually replace.  I do not recommend using `replace = true` in most use cases.